# AJAX JSONP request failing despite request showing status 200 and response payload being correct

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to complete an AJAX get request, using JSONP as my datatype to get around a CORS error that I was getting earlier. My javascript is as follows:

```
var search = document.getElementById("search_term").value;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const url = "http://myurl/" + search;
            $('.btn').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response)
                    },
                    error: function (a, b, c) {
                        console.log('Error ' + a)
                        console.log(b)
                        console.log(c)
                    }
                })
            })
        })
```

I have also tried including jsonp: false in the AJAX parameters as well as declaring a callback function, but haven't been able to have the request successfully complete, instead always entering the "error" portion of my ajax call.

The errors I receive (for the code as seen above) is as follows:

a = `Error [object Object]`

b = `parseerror`

c=

```
Error: "jQuery3410699381665356_1582645983199 was not called"
    jQuery 7
        error
        e.converters["script json"]
        s
        l
        i
        dispatch
        handle
```

As the title of this question says, the request shows as status 200 and the response payload is accurate to what I'm trying to receive.

Comment: "the response payload is accurate to what I'm trying to receive" — Well, it isn't JSONP.

Comment: JSONP is a *dirty* hack with various security issues that was used before CORS was invented. Like CORS, it only works it the API you want to request data from supports it. Use CORS instead.